# Excel Conditional Formatting for Alternating Line Color Based on Row Values (Some Duplicate some Unique) In a Large Data Set

Tags: microsoft-excel

In the data set below, Is it possible to use Conditional Formatting to highlight/fill a whole row based on the number in the "SO Number" Column? 
Above the green line I have done this manually to exemplify what I was hoping to achieve using Conditional Formatting. [Example of Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1WqW.png)
Any help or suggestions appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to do:

1. Create a new column to do a binary calculation that identifies changes in value of your target cells (i.e. the SO Number).
2. In new column, write formula (see image below) that identifies when the value changes between rows to indicate a new group of rows based on value of target cells (i.e. SO Number groups).
3. Highlight the entire range of data you want to apply conditional format to
4. Click "Conditional Formatting" > "New Rule"
5. Under "Select a Rule Type," select "Use a Formula to determine which cells to format" (See image below).
6. Write a basic formula that references the values created in step 2. Note, since you want the conditional formula to change with row but not column, you want to lock the column with a '$' symbol (as in the example below "$B2"
   [image]